# How to Open Another Page from a Card Click in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hey guy's I'm working on a app that has 3 cards on the home page I want each card to go to a different page based on a id that each card has so for example the math card I want to have it go to the MathHomePage and the science card I want it to go to the ScienceHomePage here's my code:

```
import 'package:appname/model/Topic.dart';

class TopicDao {

  static final List<Topic> topics = [
    const Topic(
      id: "1",
      name: "Math",
      image: "assets/img/math.png",
    ),
    const Topic(
      id: "2",
      name: "Science",
      image: "assets/img/science.png",
    ),
    const Topic(
      id: "3",
      name: "English",
      image: "assets/img/english.png",
    ),

  ];





   //I think I can use this code somehow to make it go to the pages.
  static Topic getTopicById(id) {
    return topics
        .where((p) => p.id == id)
        .first;




  }






}
```

Here's The Topic Class:

```
class Topic {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String image;


  const Topic({this.id, this.name, this.image});


}
```

I'm still very new to flutter so any help would be amazing!!!!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use *navigator class* to go to a different page
       
 `onTap: () {
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SecondScreen(id),
        ));
}`

If you are using a list to render the three cards then you can use its `onTap()` method and  call another class inside *nevigator* and pass it the ID based on which you can display the different pages.
More here: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! I am using the list to render the three cards when I use your answer I get this error: error: Undefined name 'onTap'. any other help would be amazing!

Comment: @Phoneswapshop `onTap()` will work on either *ListTile* or *GestureDetector* so you need to wrap your list items inside that to be able to use it. Sharing your code may help further.